# context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Tags: go, http, connection-pooling, httpconnection

Since last month I'm seeing strange behaviour in my application.

I have an k8 go http application where I'm calling internal Go http services within the organization.

Service A calling Service B.
In service A I'm getting error while calling service B of:

> context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

I have checked APM of service B and its response time is in control still we keep getting above errors randomly in service A.
The average response time of service B is 2 ms and in APM its not going beyond 50 MS at any cost which I have verified. Also there are no error logs.

In my service A I'm using HTTP connection pooling and keeping the single instance of HTTP client throughout the application life cycle.
I also checked HTTP connections in Service A using netstat in k8 POD and that seems to be within control as well during the issue.

Please find my HTTP client connection policy for service A

**Generic function to create client:**

```
func DefaultHTTPClient(httpConfig *config.HTTPConfig) *http.Client {
    transport := &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
        DialContext: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout:   time.Duration(httpConfig.ConnectionTimeout) * time.Millisecond,
            KeepAlive: time.Duration(httpConfig.KeepAlive) * time.Millisecond,
            DualStack: true,
        }).DialContext,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout: time.Duration(httpConfig.TLSHandshakeTimeout) * time.Millisecond,

        MaxIdleConns:        httpConfig.DefaultMaxIdleConns,
        MaxIdleConnsPerHost: httpConfig.DefaultMaxIdleConns,
        IdleConnTimeout:     time.Duration(httpConfig.IdleConnectionTimeout) * time.Millisecond,
        Dial:                setupDialTimeOut(httpConfig),
    }

    return &http.Client{
        Timeout:   time.Duration(httpConfig.RequestTimeout) * time.Millisecond,
        Transport: transport,
    }
}
```

HTTP Policy :

```
defaultMaxIdleConns: 50
defaultMaxIdleConnsPerHost: 50
idleConnectionTimeout: 90000
requestTimeout: 300
connectionTimeout: 1000
keepAlive: 60000
tlsHandshakeTimeout: 1000
apiKey: "1231243214214"
retryConfig:
  enabled: true
  intervals: [100, 200, 400]
```

I tried several things still not able to debug this issue.
Need help to debug and resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you check service B is able to sever traffic? You can make direct call to service B to check it.

Comment: There's not really enough information to diagnose how your live programs are behaving. However, one thing that I've seen teams be surprised by is CPU throttling causing timeouts. If your pods aren't getting enough time slices, then by the time they get a chance to execute the timeout can be exceeded.

Comment: @ShalauddinAhamadShuza Service B is working properly. We checked curl from service A POD to Service B POD and its working. This issue in happening randomly..

Comment: @coxley I checked memory and CPU utilizations when this issue occurs and they seems to be normal and under control

Comment: CPU usage doesn't necessarily imply there's no throttling. There can be spikes at a smaller granularity than are observed by monitoring. I'm not sure what metrics are available to you, but if you have a cpu _throttling_ specific one then that'd be best to look at.

Comment: Overall, this question is impossible to answer because it's highly environment dependent. If there can't be a minimum, reproducible example, I'm afraid it's likely off-topic for SO.

Comment: As a check, I'd scale up B by 1 and see how it goes. That's what HPA is for.

Comment: @sureshrajput you need to monitor service B when it happens. There must me something that is contributing to the error like after what interval it happen or after how many request it happen. Did you check those possibilities?